# missing plugin when i use shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Good day , I am trying to use flutter shared preferences . I enter the code below in the MAin.dart page

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  static Future init() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

Than in the login page i want to save the data greceived from API into shared preference the code velow shows it . The aim is to save the ID if login successfull to use that ID later on in every page

```
var me3 = jsondata["dd"];

            final SharedPreferences id = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            prefs.setString('id', "$me3");

            Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SearchPage(),),);
```

Than after login i want to call the me3 variable to use it but i get this error ->Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

how can i fix this error

Comment: Check your pubspec.yaml file if the dependencies is "shared_preferences: ^2.0.8". Then the command line : flutter clean and flutter pub get.  And Why "final SharedPreferences id" is not "final SharedPreferences prefs"?

Comment: no reason why i put final , I was struggling so thought final would help

Comment: can show the code where you are trying to get the value?